# C# Find selected control on any window

Tags: c#, api, childwindow

What would be the best way to go about finding what the active control is on any window? I am going to be sending the WM_PASTE message to it. ChildWindowFromPoint has not been returning a fair few of the selected controls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, yeah. WM_Paste....

Winform application?

Why do you assume that the active window can receive them? I mean, unless it is an activeX control.... it would not ahve it's own lower level message pump. It would react on events propagated within the .NET framework... only active x (native) controls an dthe window IIRC handle windows messages.

Comment: Yes a WinForms application. Isn't using Ctrl+V sending the WM_PASTE message?

Comment: Yes it is - but only to the WINDOW... from there thigns bubble down as .NET events ;)

Answer (score 1):

[GetFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646294(v=VS.85).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I had tried this but it doesn't seem to be able to get windows outside of my application?